# How to get all data from Redis to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, redis, node-redis

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var coordiante = [];
multi = client.multi();
multi.exec(function(err, res) {
client.lrange('S4' , 0 ,5 ,function(err, len){
     len.forEach(function (index,item) {
        coordiante[item] = index;
  })
     client.quit();
 });
});
console.log(coordiante);
```

i want to use coordiante array here, but coordinate is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you are getting a proper response by putting a console.log in following loops :

```
   multi.exec(function(err, res) {
     console.log(res);
     console.log(err);
     client.lrange('S4' , 0 ,5 ,function(err, len){
       console.log(len);
         len.forEach(function (index,item) {
         coordiante[item] = index;
       })
      client.quit();
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If we go on [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#clienthgetallhash-callback) project page and read through it accurately, we will meet this strings.

### **client.hgetall(hash, callback)**

The reply from an HGETALL command will be converted into a **JavaScript
   Object** by node_redis. That way you can interact with the responses
   using JavaScript syntax.

```
Example:

client.hmset("hosts", "mjr", "1", "another", "23", "home", "1234");
client.hgetall("hosts", function (err, obj) {
  console.dir(obj);
});
Output:

{ mjr: '1', another: '23', home: '1234' }
```

so everything you need to do is client.hgetall()